# Fixed number of parameter pack elements to initialize templated class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

The general idea is to have a generic class to represent a point in n-dimensional space ("class Point"). It should take any number of arguments as long as they are of the same type.
I did this using variadic template parameter packs and it appears to work fine.

Now I want a simple alias, something like "Point2i" which takes only integer parameters (easy, just specify type T) and only two parameters (to hint at a two dimensional space) at a time (this is where I failed so far).

```
/**
 * @brief Point in n-dimensional space.
 */
template <typename T = int> class Point {
public:
    /**
     * @brief Default constructor for an empty polygon.
     * Points have to be added manually via @ref add_point.
     */
    template <typename... Ts>
    Point(Ts... coords) {
        m_coordinates = { std::forward<Ts>(coords)... };
    }

    /**
     * @brief Dimensions of the point coordinate space.
     * @return Number of dimensions.
     */
    size_t dims() const {
        return m_coordinates.size();
    }

    /**
     * @brief Array subscript operator.
     * @param dim The dimension you want.
     * @return The coordinate in the specified dimension.
     */
    T& operator[] (const size_t &dim) {
        return m_coordinates[dim];
    }

private:
    /// Coordinates of the point in n-dimensional space, where n = vector size.
    std::vector<T> m_coordinates;
};

template <typename... Ts, typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 2>::type>
using Point2i = Point<int>(Ts...);
```

The problem is in the last two lines: the "Point2i" stuff just does not work. The error I get from GCC 9 is: "point.h:52:23: error: template parameter pack must be the last template parameter".

Line 52 is the line with "template

Any idea how to make this work the way I want? I guess it's quite easy for someone seasoned in C++ template metaprogramming.

Comment: You can’t create a type alias to a specific call to the constructor

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use class with dynamically allocated array for 2 dimensional points. This will cause a huge hit to performance. You ought to write a separate class with a staticaly allocated data, either via `T val[N];` or `std::array<T,N> val;`.

Comment: Another issue, it isn't a good idea to use template parameter pack constructor for the `Point` class. You'd better write a simple non-template constructor via `std::initializer_list<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not template the class based on the n-dimensions you want to work with? Then you can eliminate overloads when the number of elements don't match the dimensions:

```c++
template<class T, int N=-1> // -1 means dimensions are not specified
class Point {
public:
  template<class... Ts, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ts), N) == -1>* = nullptr>
  Point(Ts... coords) : m_coordinates{ coords... }
  { }

  template<class... Ts, std::enable_if_t<(N != -1 && sizeof...(Ts) == N)>* = nullptr>
  Point(Ts... coords) : m_coordinates{ coords... }
  { }
  // ...
};
using Point2i = Point<int, 2>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible a `using` for a constructor of a class.

The best I can imagine is a classic `make_something()` function.

I mean... something as

```
template <typename... Ts,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 2>::type>
Point<int> Point2i (Ts... ts)
 { return { ts... }; }
```

Off Topic Unrequested Suggestion 1: use, when possible, constructor initialization lists; avoid (when possible) initialization inside the body of a constructor

I mean... instead of

```
template <typename... Ts>
Point(Ts... coords) {
    m_coordinates = { std::forward<Ts>(coords)... };
}
```

is better

```
template <typename... Ts>
Point (Ts ... coords) : m_coordinates { std::forward<Ts>(coords)... }
 { }
```

Off Topic Unrequested Suggestion 2: if you want to use perfect forwarding, use forwarding references.

So the constructor become

```
template <typename... Ts>
Point (Ts && ... coords) : m_coordinates { std::forward<Ts>(coords)... }
 { } //   ^^ <-- add forwarding references
```

Also in the `point2i` function

```
template <typename... Ts,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 2>::type>
Point<int> Point2i (Ts && ... ts) 
 { return { std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }; }
```

Off Topic Unrequested Suggestion 3: I suppose that your `Point` objects are intended of fixed size. In this case, I suggest to take in consideration the hypotheses of add the size of the point as template parameter. This way you can use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.